# Is it possible to pass the datalog wildcard `_` into a parameterized query?

Tags: database, datomic, datalog

Is it possible to pass a wildcard `_` into a parameterized query? Something like this:

```
(d/q [:find ?e
      :in $ ?type
      :where [?e :type ?type]] db _)
```

When I tried this as written above it threw an error. Is there a way to do this?

I know that I can get everything with a query that looks like this:

(d/q [:find ?e
      :where [?e :type]] db)

But my goal is to avoid needing to build separate queries when I don't want to filter results by `:type`. The use case is, e.g., and API endpoint that may or may not filter results.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to type:

```
(d/q [:find ?e
      :in $
      :where [?e :type]] db )
```

In Datomic, any unspecified values are considered to be wildcards. The above query will return a list of all entities that have the `:type` attribute, regardless of value.

## Update

Datomic's query is designed to accept a plain value like `5` or `:awesome` to be substituted into the `?type` variable. A symbol like `_` (or the quoted version `'_`) does not fit the pattern expected by Datomic.

Just for fun, I tried several variations and could not get it Datomic to accept the symbol '_ for the `?type` variable in the way you proposed.  I think you'll have to write a separate query for the wildcard case.

Essentially, the wildcard `_` is a special symbol (aka "reserved word") in the Datomic query syntax just like `$`. Datomic also enforces that query variables begin with a `?` like `?e` or `?type`.  These requirements are a part of the Datomic DSL that you can't change.

The only workaround besides hand-writing separate queries would be to dynamically compose the query vector from a base-part and add-on parts. Whether that is easier or harder than hand-writing the different queries depends on your specific situation.

Comment: I should have provided more context. This is for a api endpoint that fetches results with or without a filter applied. What I'm trying to avoid is needing to construct a different query structure when there's no filter by specific `:type` because building separate queries creates a mess of code, whereas being able to supply a wildcard would be more concise.